# Why my System can not find one of two mp3 files which are in the same folder?

Tags: javafx-8

I just want to have 2 Objects from Type "Media". Therefore i have 2 .mp3 files.
The first is no problem, i can play it.
But if i enable the Code for the second file, the System throws an Error
"InvocationtargetException" it says "System can not find the file"

I checked both paths of the .mp3 files, here are the results:

> file:/C:/Users/Lennie-Admin/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Lost/Rise.mp3
>
> file:/C:/Users/Lennie-Admin/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Lost/TrueStrength.mp3

I checked my working directory with `System.out.println( new File("").getAbsolutePath());` the Result is

> C:\Users\Lennie-Admin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Lost

And finally here is the java Code, which should create the 2 Objects:

```
String uriString1 = new File("Rise.mp3").toURI().toString();
Media hit1 = new Media(uriString1);
String uriString2 = new File("TrueStrength.mp3").toURI().toString();
Media hit2 = new Media(uriString2);
```

Hope you can help me :)

Comment: First try rebuilding your project. Then try renaming the 2nd file. Then try changing the playing order of that two. Then try with 3rd new file. HTH!

Comment: WoW, Renaming...that was too simple!!! Thanks it worked!!! :)